# Не определяется параметр

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Изучаю JavaScript посредством создания Discord бота, появилась необходимость сделать базовый Handler для команд и тут начались проблемы.**

```
dcd_client.command = new DiscordJS.Collection();
const commands = fs.readdirSync("../commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))

for (file of commands) {
    const command = require(`../commands/${commandName}`)
    const commandName = file.split(".")[0]
    dcd_client.commands.set(commandName, command)
}

dcd_client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
        const commadName = args.shift()
        const command = dcd_client.commands.get(commadName)
        if (!command) return
        command.run(dcd_client, message, args)
    }
})
```

я так понимаю проблема заключается в .filter()
При запуске выдает такую ошибку:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
file:///mnt/d/BOT/Ultima/src/app.js:325
for (file of commands) {
     ^

ReferenceError: file is not defined
    at file:///mnt/d/BOT/cards/bot/Ultima/src/app.js:325:6
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:85:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)

Node.js v18.2.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Что мне надо сделать чтобы он определял file?

Comment: можно использовать асинхронный метод fs.readdir() https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdir-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис цикла **for .. of** (**for .. in** тоже) должен выглядеть так:

```
for (const item of array) {
    ...
}

for (const item in array) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло !
Может вы знаете как заменить 
```const command = require(`../commands/${commandName}`)```  на Import ?
 Из-за использования ES module, просит использовать Import, но при этом выдает ошибку SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: const command = await import(...)